# How to convert table format layout in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I've been searching for hours a solution about my issue but I can't find any.
My task is to convert the layout of this raw data tabular format in to a new format similar with a Pivot Table.

Do you have any idea on how I can easily convert it? Maybe using VBA or something.

I'm tired of doing this manually using transpose. I hope someone could help me automate this. Thanks in advance!

[sample file image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/virf7.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can obtain your desired output using `Power Query`, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Office 365 Excel.  It is a very simple UNpivot operation

- Select some cell in your original table
- `Data => Get&Transform => From Table/Range`
- When the PQ UI opens, navigate to `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table Name in Line 2 of the code.
- Replace the existing code with the **M-Code** below
- Change the table name in line 2 of the pasted code to your "real" table name
- Examine any comments, and also the `Applied Steps` window, to better understand the algorithm and steps

**M Code**

```
let

//Change table name in next line to actual table name
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table5"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
            {"Branch", type text}, {"Product 1", Int64.Type}, {"Product 2", Int64.Type}, 
            {"Product 3", Int64.Type}, {"Product 4", Int64.Type}, {"Product 5", Int64.Type}
        }),

//Here is where the magic happens
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Branch"}, "Attribute", "Value")
in
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns"
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ron, this is amazing. I will try this solution now. Will get back to you shortly :)

Comment: Amazing! I finally got it worked! Thanks a lot! You are my hero! :)